# 'numpy.ndarray' : object is not callable error

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to visualize Logistic Regression on the training data set and here's the snippet of code when running encounters ('numpy.ndarray' object is not callable) error.

How to fix this?

`for i,j in enumerate(np.unique(Y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set(Y_set == j,0), X_set(Y_set == j, 1),
                c=ListedColormap(('red','green'))(i),label = j)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: In Python indexing uses `[]`, function calls use `()`.  We guess that you intend `scatter(...)` to be a function call.  But what is `x_set(...)`?  A function call? or indexing?  Explain.  If the answers don't help, explain what you are trying do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It's hard to see where the error is because we have no idea what X_set and Y_set are... but I'm going to guess they are numpy.ndarrays. If they are, the error is how you are referring to them in the scatter call. You should use square brackets to index into your sets instead of the parentheses (which try to 'call' the object like a function).

```py
for i,j in enumerate(np.unique(Y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[Y_set == j,0], X_set[Y_set == j, 1],
                c=ListedColormap(('red','green'))(i),label = j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the square brackets to index into your sets this might work.

```
 plt.scatter(X_set[Y_set == j,0], X_set[Y_set == j, 1],
```